# .net n-layer website structural advice required

Tags: c#, .net, n-layer

I'm creating my first .net/c# website using Entity Framework as my data access layer. I've split my project into layers so that I have DataAccess, BusinessLogic, a separate BusinessObjects layer and the website itself is the UI (Pages/UserControls/Appcode folder). There is also an additional Utilities plugin project.

The EF model has gone in DA, whilst the entity creation has gone into BO. All feels good, but I'm having trouble what logic class belongs in AppCode (UI) and what belongs in BusinessLogic.

Are there any guidelines that can help me determine which side of the line things go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App_Code is just a handy convenience for you to run code. I would advise you to avoid using that folder. Just create class library projects for all your classes, which would comprise your business logic layer. In the web project, only put pages and controls (ASCX and ASPX files). It makes the logical separation clearer.

Comment: Thanks Slavo, thats what I was looking for - some real world advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference implementation from Microsoft Spain; which employs EF, Unity, WCF etc. But, note that this implementation may be overengineered for your needs. Before implementation, instead of copying the same structure, it is better for you to decide, which parts, concepts, patterns are useful for you and which are not.

[Microsoft N Layer Reference Implementation](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/)